# What is the jet luminosity of this quasar (ULAS J1120+0641)?

Tags: cosmology, black-holes, astrophysics, accretion-disk

In wikipedia I found that its luminosity is $6.3×10^{13}$ solar luminosities, but is that the luminosity of the jet itself or is that the luminosity of the entire system (the jet + the accretion disk) ? Also, how much matter does the black hole of this quasar accrete for any given time?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no evidence yet that ULAS J1120+0641 has a jet. The reported luminosity is presumably that of the whole system, powered by accretion onto the supermassive black hole. The accretion rate for $6.3\times 10^{13}$ solar luminosities can only be estimated if the mass of the supermassive black hole is constrained.

Comment: you could estimate the accretion rate as the Eddington accretion rate $M_{Edd}=L/(\eta c^2)$ where $L$ is the luminosity and $\eta$ is the efficiency (usually assumed to be $\approx 0.1$.)